# Is it dangerous to wake a sleepwalker?

Tags: medical-science, neurology, sleep

[image: Sleepwalker] <sup>[Source](http://www.jokeroo.com/pictures/other/why-do-people-sleepwalk.html)</sup>

It seems to be a [common belief](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NeverWakeUpASleepwalker) that you should

> **never wake up a sleepwalker**

From [Wikipedia - Sleepwalking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleepwalking#Treatment):

> **There are conflicting viewpoints on whether it is harmful to wake a sleepwalker.**
>
> - Some experts say that sleepwalkers should be gently guided back to bed without waking them.
> - Others counter that idea and state that waking a sleepwalker may result in their disorientation, but it is not harmful.

My question is, does waking a sleepwalker cause any harm?

Comment: I had a girlfried that was sleep**t**alking, was extremely funny to reply to her. Actually sometimes that did piss her off, so I would not reccommend ;)

Answer (score 1):

A recent article [Awake or Knocked Out? The Line Gets Blurrier](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/04/17/science/studying-states-of-consciousness.html) by James Gorman, published on April 12, 2012 in the *New York Times*, talks about experiments involving different states of consciousness.

According to what I infer from this article, if you 'wake' a sleepwalker you're then interacting with someone whose 'higher' brain function (i.e. the neocortex: I assume you know what that is) isn't active and in control.

Summary:

1. do not expect an intelligent reaction
2. some unintelligent reactions are dangerous
3. apart from that it's harmless (though bewildering, perhaps annoying)

---

See also en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castle_doctrine#Origins

> How is the Castle doctrine relevant? I jokingly expected sleepwalking to be an exception to the idea that a natural right existed to kill a robber or other home invader. But, I saw no mention of sleepwalking...

That citation starts with Exodus 22:2-3 saying: "it's OK to kill someone who invades your house" (I read: sleep) "during the night, but not ok during the day" (I read: awake). Also, re. castle doctrine: if you interact with someone in their sleep, and if they irrationally choose to be dangerous, they have no duty to retreat.

No duty to retreat: not because they're (sleepwalking) in their own house, but because they're unconscious (irresponsible, incapable of 'mens rea').

---

An example from the news, of someone waking up their co-pilot: [Groggy Air Canada pilot ... caused injuries in jet dive: report](http://www.theglobeandmail.com/news/national/groggy-air-canada-pilot-unbuckled-seatbelts-caused-injuries-in-jet-dive-report/article2403820/).

Comment: How is the Castle doctrine relevant? I jokingly expected sleepwalking to be an exception to the idea that a natural right existed to kill a robber or other home invader.  But, I saw no mention of sleepwalking...

Comment: Could this comment be misplaced, i.e. posted with the wrong answer/article?