# Is it possible to drive while sleepwalking?

Tags: medical-science, sleep

I recently watched a movie called [*In My Sleep*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0326965/) where the character allegedly is able to drive and even have sex while he is "sleepwalking."

> Marcus struggles with parasomnia, a sleepwalking disorder that causes him to do things in his sleep that he cannot remember the next day.

In the movie, Marcus has a conversation with his doctor (or whatever he's called):

> Marcus: What's a parasomniac?
>   Doctor: Someone who can do just about anything while they're sleeping.
>   Marcus: Drive a car?
>   Doctor: Yes.
>   Marcus: Make love?
>   Doctor: There are documented cases of that.
>   Marcus: Swim? Which is the one thing I *haven't* done.
>   Doctor: I've never heard of anyone swimming while sleepwalking...

Is it possible to do things such as this while sleepwalking? What all *can* a person do while sleepwalking?

Comment: Related question: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8895/is-it-dangerous-to-wake-a-sleepwalker

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is closer to your question: [What Drives Sleep-Driving?](http://psychcentral.com/blog/archives/2007/03/14/what-drives-sleep-driving/)

> The FDA has announced it will require makers of certain sleeping pills
>   to warn consumers about serious side effects including allergic
>   reactions and sleep-driving.
>
> Somnambulism (sleep-walking) incidents involving complex tasks like
>   driving, preparing and eating food, and having sex while asleep, with
>   no memory of the tasks when awakened, have made the news in recent
>   years. Now the FDA wants consumers and doctors to have direct warnings
>   on labels and in brochures.
>
> The Z-drugs are a class of drugs called pyrazolopyrimidines, the
>   best-known being zolpidem (Ambien), eszopiclone (Lunesta, Imovane),
>   and zalepron (Sonata).

[Somnambulism](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmedhealth/PMH0001811/) reference.

> **Calling your health care provider**
>   You probably won't need to visit your health care provider if you are
>   sleepwalking.
>   However, discuss the condition with your doctor if:
>   - You also have other symptoms
>   - Sleepwalking is frequent or persistent
>   - You perform potentially dangerous activities (**such as driving**) while
>   sleepwalking

---

Older data.
[Can people drive while asleep?](http://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/sleepless-in-america/200812/can-people-drive-while-asleep) <sub>from December 6, 2008 by John Cline</sub>.

> Some sleep walkers have actually driven, sometimes for significant
>   distances. This is a frightening possibility as sleep walkers can be
>   injured while sleepwalking and most certainly can injure themselves or
>   others while sleep driving. Amazingly sleep drivers have been able to
>   get from one location to another without ever waking up. We do not
>   know how many driving fatalities may have resulted from sleep driving.

John Cline is a clinical psychologist, Diplomate of the the American Board of Sleep Medicine, a fellow of the American Academy of Sleep Medicine and a clinical professor at Yale University.
I'd still like to see some more references tho...